# Can I determine whether MFMailComposeViewController will use S/MIME or not?

Tags: iphone, ios, smime

I would like to use standard MFMailComposeViewController but I need to tell user, whether message that was sent was sent with S/MIME (in fact I need to disable email creation if S/MIME is disabled). I understand that it is a strange request, but anyway, is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not via public APIs at least. Besides, why on earth do you need this?!

Comment: Some app requirement. One of the strangest :) I think that I'll try to  convince my customer to go with another solution. But I'd like to be sure that this is not possible.

Comment: Not unless you want to use undoumented APIs and have your app rejected. I've scoured the docs, and there is no mention of it. Sorry!

Comment: Yes, I did that too. But docs are huge, maybe somewhere... Ok, I think, I can select this as a correct answer. Thanks.

Comment: Ok thanks. If I do find something I'll update my answer, but don't hold your breath!